# how to pipe a python script to a command (boost::program::options)

Tags: python, c++, boost, pipe, boost-program-options

I am trying to redirect(in windows) the output of a python file to the stdin of a command created with boost::program::options like this:

```
python test.py | command.exe -s
```

test.py just prints the content of a file:

```
f = open('test.xml', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

If i execute just the python file it works but if i try to pipe it to the other command it fails with the following error:

```
close failed in the file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missin
lost sys.stderr
```

If i try to execute this `command.exe -s < test.xml` it works fine so i guess is a problem with pipe.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: You get this error because when CMD is creating pipe, it's closing STDERR. And somehow method `close()` of file obejct in python need to use this descriptor which is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because when **CMD** is creating pipe, it's closing **STDERR**. And somehow method `close()` of file obejct in python need to use this descriptor which is missing.

And possible solution could be like this :
https://superuser.com/questions/452763/how-to-pipleline-stderr-in-cmd-exe